# How is levulinic acid formed from sucrose?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbohydrates

I came across the following question:

Sucrose on treatment with conc. $\ce {HCl}$ produces?
The answer is given as levulinic acid.

So how exactly does sucrose produce levulinic acid?

Comment: Google is your friend! Search "Levulinic acid from Sucrose" and you will find.

Comment: @Waylander I found this: http://www.orgsyn.org/content/figures/CV1P0335.gif but I've always learned that $\ce {C_{12}H_{22}O_{11} + H_2O + HCl->}$ D-glucose + D-fructose. How could I've understood that the question demanded levulinic acid?

Comment: Levulinic acid can be produced from both fructose or glucose (they can isomerise into each other) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levulinic_acid,  https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlehtml/2018/nj/c7nj03146g

Answer (score 3):

The internet links provided in the Comments do not give much detail as to the stepwise mechanism for the transformation of fructose **1** to levulinic acid **12**. I presume that you recognize that the sucrose acetal linkage is hydrolyzed in aqueous acid and that the resultant (+)-D-glucose and (-)-D-fructose are interconvertible via enolization of the carbonyl group. As a monomer, fructose **1** prefers the pyranose closed form over the furanose form **2**. Facile loss of water from **2** forms cation **3** that, via the enol **4**, affords aldehyde **5**. Acid-catalyzed loss of two equivalents of water (steps not shown but straightforward) from **5** leads to 5-hydroxymethylfurfural (**6**). Cation **7** is formed  and is hydrated to provide **8**. Hydration of the formyl group forms **9** followed by loss of formic acid affording 2-hydroxy-5-methylfuran **10**. 2-Hydroxyfurans readily tautomerize to the keto form, in this instance to the enol lactone **11**. Hydrolysis of **11** affords levulinic acid **12**. I presume that the name levulinic acid arises because it is derived from (-)-fructose, aka, levulose, a name derived from the sign of its optical rotation. You may want to compare the similarities of this mechanism with the one offered by user55119 [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/8638/whats-the-mechanism-of-the-reaction-of-e-methyl-3-furan-2-ylacrylate-in-aci/86285#86285).
[image]
[image]